# Answering a question then flagging it as low quality

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts

Recently I answered a very low quality question from a new user. My reason behind this is I want him to welcome and learn the proper asking of question (that's why I answer the question), but on the other hand I dont want to tolerate such question (so I flagged it as a low quality). **The question is am I wrong in doing this,if yes what is the best way to treat the user in that case?** My effort is not in vain because I usher him to asking a good question which may later be beneficial to him.

I believed that stackoverflow is not just about reputation, it is about helping others even at the cost of our time and effort which in return will not benefit us.

> [image: Figure 1: My Answer to the Low Quality Question]

I can't submit my comment on that image because the question has been flagged 10 times as a low quality question.

Comment: "I believed that stackoverflow is not just about reputation, it is about helping others" - No. The goal of SO is to build a high-quality knowledge repository where people can find answers to programming problems. Helping individual askers is only a side effect. And if somebody is unable or unwilling to work towards this goal (by posting good questions or answers, doing helpful edits, etc), we do _not_ want them to feel welcome. Btw, no idea what the question was but your answer is basically a link-only answer with added fluff, and shouldn't have been posted as an answer anyways - use comments.

Answer (score 14):

When you flag a question as "very low quality", you are asking that the question be closed and deleted ASAP because it's so bad that **it's not even worth answering**.

By answering the question anyway, you're essentially contradicting your flag. But that doesn't change the fact that the question is untenably bad anyway, so I went ahead and deleted it. This is why I said answering such questions is a waste of your time, because now the question is gone and so is your answer with it.

Comment: Ah, okay. Now I understand. Thanks for informing me about this. I edited the question to include how do I treat this case.

Comment: @Cary Bondoc: You can leave a comment primarily to educate the user on how the site works. However I suggest not spending time answering the question - assuming there is an answerable question to begin with - because by answering you're saying that you *can* tolerate such questions.

Comment: Ah yes, yes. You are right about that.